# Pandas: Creating a matplotlib legend from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm attempting to use a dataframe to create a scatter plot. Here's an example of what the dataframe looks like:

```
----------------------------------------------
| Index   |   x  |   y  |  color   |  name   |
----------------------------------------------
|    0    |  4.3 |  2.2 |    'b'   |  'First'|
----------------------------------------------
|    1    |  2.3 |  3.2 |    'c'   |  'Secd' |
----------------------------------------------
```

The code I'm using to plot looks like this:

```
plt.scatter(dframe['x'], dframe['y'], color=dframe['color'], label=dframe['name'])
plt.title('Title')
plt.xlabel('X label')
plt.ylabel('Y label')
plt.xlim(0, 10)
plt.ylim(0, 10)
plt.legend(scatterpoints=1, loc='lower left', fontsize=10)
plt.show()
```

For whatever reason, this adds 1 item to the legend and the label for that item is the entire 'name' column repeated 2x.

How can I get the legend to display each item separately in the name column and only show that column once?

Thanks!

As info, I have tried the following to no avail:

```
plt.legend(dframe['name'], loc = 'lower....

for i in range(len(dframe['name'])):
    plt.legend(dframe['name'][i], loc = .. 

plt.legend([dframe['name']], loc = 'lower....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`plt.scatter` gets only one legend label per call. If you want to have a label for each point, you'd have to do something like this:

```
for index, row in dframe.iterrows():
    plt.scatter(row['x'], row['y'], color=row['color'], label=row['name'])
plt.title('Title')
plt.xlabel('X label')
plt.ylabel('Y label')
plt.xlim(0, 10)
plt.ylim(0, 10)
plt.legend(scatterpoints=1, loc='lower left', fontsize=10)
plt.show()
```